# How to store a particular part of the file in a variable in expect?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to retrieve the part of the file content to be saved in a variable.
example:

```
@V08.4.14 F002 qwerty asdfgh zxcvb .....
```

I have this as a line in the file. I want only "`V08.4.14F002`" stored in the variable with no space between them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to be exactly certain without knowing how the text can vary, but the `regsub` command can do this transformation:

```
set myVariable [regsub {^@(V[\d.]+) (F\d+) .*} $data {\1\2}]
```

To read a line in from a file (in this case, just the first line), you do:

```
set f [open "theFile.txt"]
set data [gets $f]
close $f
```